# Secure protocol for a backup server?

Tags: ssh, server, cloud-computing, tcp, sftp

I want to make a back up system in my home, but I don't know I should use a FTP server or a TPC-based cloud server or a SSH-based server. Which method is best in security?

I just want to upload and download files to a pc in my home from internet

Thank you

Comment: This type of broad question doesn't work well on StackExchange. There are too many possible answers. Can you make the question more specific? Phrases like "most secure" don't really help. Do you mean secure against people breaking into your house and stealing your backup server? Against people on your home net? Against your neighbors?

Comment: I mean secure against breaking system and enter my home server, and sorry for type of question, I didn't knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to download/upload your data over SSH, at least this has the advantage of ensuring data encryption ([Understanding the SSH Encryption and Connection Process](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process)); however this does not protect you against [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks ([Quick and Easy SSH MITM](http://andrewmichaelsmith.com/2014/03/quick-and-easy-ssh-mitm/)). It is safer to SSH over SSL ([SSH over SSL, a quick and minimal config.](http://blog.chmd.fr/ssh-over-ssl-a-quick-and-minimal-config.html) ).

Answer (score 2):

**Manual Transfers**

For manual uploads / downloads I recommend using SFTP / SSH over using FTP as FTP generally does not encrypt its communication channel.

**Automated Transfers**

If you want to automatically synchronise files between a server and your home machine, I'd recommend using rsync.

This link should get you started: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=15082